# REST API for a PHP Web application

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I am working on a API for my web application written in CodeIgniter. This is my first time writing a API.

What is the best way of imposing a API limit on the API?

Thanks for your time

Comment: by limit, I mean the number of requests per hour for a particular user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log the user's credentials (if he has to provide them) or his IP address, the request (optional) and a timestamp in a database.

Now, for every request, you delete records where the timestamp is more than an hour ago, check how many requests for that user are still in the table, and if that is more than your limit, deny the request.

Simple solution, keep in mind, though, there might be more performant solutions out there.

Pretty straight forward. If that doesn't answer your question, please provide more details.
I don't see how this is codeigniter related, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.I added CodeIgniter to the tag as I was building it on top of CodeIgniter Framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my REST_Controller to do basically all of this for you:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

I recently added in some key logging, request limiting features in so this can all be done through config.

Comment: Thanks Phil. I am using the REST Controller written by you at this moment with a few modification. Thanks for open sourcing the code.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is consider using an external service to impose API limits and provide API management functionality in general.

For example, my company, WebServius ( http://www.webservius.com ) provides a layer that sits in front of your API and can provide per-user throttling (e.g. requests per API key per hour), API-wide throttling (e.g. total requests per hour), adaptive throttling (where throttling limits decrease as API response time increases), etc, with other features coming soon (e.g. IP-address-based throttling). It also provides a page for user registration / issuing API keys, and many other useful features.

Of course, you may also want to look at our competitors, such as Mashery or Apigee.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I did try Webservius. The UI looked a lot complicated, which made me leave. Will give it another try.

Comment: Feel free to contact me directly ( eugene at webservius dot com ) and I will make sure that you will get as much help as necessary to make everything work. I am also very interested in feedback about how we can improve our UI.